# JDA Bot Exception

Tags: java, discord-jda

I have a problem while creating a Java bot for Discord. I decided to make a command for it to kick players from the server. But I ran into difficulties.

Here's a code :

```
package com.company;

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.EmbedBuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.Permission;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Member;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.guild.GuildMessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class KickComm extends ListenerAdapter {

    public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
        String[] args = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split("\\s+");

        List<Member> mentionedMembers = event.getMessage().getMentionedMembers();
        Member target = mentionedMembers.get(0);

        if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(Main.prefix + "kick"))
        {
            if (args.length < 2) {                                                                  //TODO NOT WORK

                EmbedBuilder NoUser = new EmbedBuilder();
                NoUser.setColor(0xff3923);
                NoUser.setTitle("\uD83D\uDD34You need to add a <@username> and <reason>");
                NoUser.setFooter("Usage: " + Main.prefix + "kick <@username> <reason>.",
                        Objects.requireNonNull(event.getMember()).getUser().getAvatarUrl());

                event.getChannel().sendMessage(NoUser.build()).queue();

                NoUser.clear();
            }

            else if (args.length < 3) {                                                                //WORK

                EmbedBuilder NoReason = new EmbedBuilder();
                NoReason.setColor(0xff3923);
                NoReason.setTitle("\uD83D\uDD34You need to add a <reason>.");
                NoReason.setFooter("Usage: " + Main.prefix + "kick <@username> <reason>.",
                        Objects.requireNonNull(event.getMember()).getUser().getAvatarUrl());

                event.getChannel().sendMessage(NoReason.build()).queue();

                NoReason.clear();
            }

            else if(!Objects.requireNonNull(event.getMember()).hasPermission(Permission.KICK_MEMBERS)  //WORK
                &&
                     !event.getMember().canInteract(target)) {

                EmbedBuilder NoPermission = new EmbedBuilder();
                NoPermission.setColor(0xff3923);
                NoPermission.setTitle("\uD83D\uDD34You don't have permission to use this command.");
                NoPermission.setFooter("Usage: " + Main.prefix + "kick <@username> <reason>.",
                        Objects.requireNonNull(event.getMember()).getUser().getAvatarUrl());

                event.getChannel().sendMessage(NoPermission.build()).queue();

                NoPermission.clear();
            }

            else if(mentionedMembers.isEmpty()) {                                                       //TODO NOT WORK 

                EmbedBuilder NoMember = new EmbedBuilder();
                NoMember.setColor(0xff3923);
                NoMember.setTitle("\uD83D\uDD34I don't see member with this nickname.");
                NoMember.setFooter("Usage: " + Main.prefix + "kick <@username> <reason>.",
                        Objects.requireNonNull(event.getMember()).getUser().getAvatarUrl());

                event.getChannel().sendMessage(NoMember.build()).queue();

                NoMember.clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Promlem in two lines :

```
if (args.length < 2) {
```

And

```
else if(mentionedMembers.isEmpty()) {
```

Most of all, I can't understand why line 1 does not work. When I write the !kick command in the discord, the console displays an error :

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
```

I  don't know why args length is 0, it's very strange.I tried to "if-else-if" to "if", but it doesn't work.I really wanna to continue creating that command, but i don't  know what to do.

P.S.:it's not all of code, because i can't progress further due to this error.Sorry for my Google translater english and many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is caused by this line:

```java
Member target = mentionedMembers.get(0);
```

Your problem here is that not every message may mention a member. Keep in mind you also receive your own messages. If the bot only sends an embed, the content will be empty.

If the content is only whitespace your `split("\\s+")` will return an empty array. This will cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` on this line:

```java
if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(Main.prefix + "kick"))
```

I would recommend checking for the length of `mentionedMembers` and checking for the length of `args` before trying to access their respective elements.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try to do this now